# Which OOP approach to choose?

Tags: typescript, oop

There is  entity as article. User can `add/edit` it.

`Edit` and `Add` forms are similar, therefore validation for them is the same.

When user submits form it should choose strategy, what to do: `add` or `update`.

Which OOP approach to choose?

Strategy pattern?

**Now it looks:**

```
if(this.dialogAction === "add") {
  // LOGIC ADD
}

if(this.dialogAction === "edit") {
 // LOGIC EDIT
}
```

Should I create two classes `AddClass` and `EditClass`, `ValidationClass`?

Both of them use `ValidationClass`.

Difference only beetween actions.

Action add uses service: `service.add();`
Edit actions uses method from service: `service.edit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need the strategy pattern. Your algorithm is well-defined and consists of two steps: validation (1), and action execution (2).

```
algorithm() {
    validate();
    action.execute();
}
```

`action` might be a [command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and there would be `AddCommand` and `EditCommand`. When the user submits the form, you let the algorithm to know what command to use.

Comment: This `action.execute();` also calls different methods, but from one service

Comment: @OPV you receive a fully-constructed `Action` with all its dependencies already set/injected. You don't care what exactly this `action` is going to do. It doesn't rely on context but may take parameters through the `execute` method.

Comment: @OPV I can't understand why it's a problem...